# Unexpected Manipulate behavior in 11.1

Tags: manipulate

I am reporting an unexpected behavior of the Manipulate statement. In the `Manipulate[expression, {par, parmin, parmax}]` previously by default the freshly evaluated expression has been hold at the value of the parameter equal to `parmin`.

Here are two statements. In the first statement the initial value of the parameter `y` is not specified, and should by default be 0:

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[-3 x^2, {x, 0, Sqrt[y]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-7, 1}}],
 {y, 0, 3}]
```

It yields the following view with the error:
[image],

while the statement

```
    Manipulate[
 Plot[-3 x^2, {x, 0, Sqrt[y]}, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-7, 1}}],
 {{y, 1}, 0, 3}]
```

with the specified initial value of the parameter `y` gives the following outcome:

[image]

One should also mention that in the first case any motion of the slider generates a correct work of the manipulate. However, as just evaluated it does not work.

This started after I have installed the Mma 11.1 on Win7.

Comment: @Kuba In my understanding according to documentation Manipulate should assign the initial value of var (that is, 0 in your example) to the expression.

Comment: `Manipulate[
 Plot[-3 x^2, {x, 0, Sqrt[y]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {-7, 1}}], {y, $MachineEpsilon, 3}]` behaves expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is expected and can be reduced to:

```
var = 0; 
Plot[-3 x^2, {x, 0, var}]
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> Plot[-3 x^2, {x, 0, var}]
> ```

So the range spec: `{x, 0, 0}` doesn't make sense for `Plot` and it returns `Unevalauted` input, which means that `0` won't be there in `var` place because `Plot` is `HoldAll`.

As soon as you move the slider the body is triggered and now the value makes sense for `Plot` which results in a graphics.

Here is a custom minimal example:

```
f // Attributes = {HoldAll};
f[x_] := x + 1 /; (x > 0)
var = 0;
f[var]
f[2]
Manipulate[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]